# If the Death star make a jump through hyperspace why didn't if arrive with the super laser facing Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

I am asking if, hypothetically, The death star jumps to Yavin through hyperspace, but it lands with the super laser facing the other way, why? I mean wouldn't it have been easier for the empire to jump facing the planet. I mean i know it would ruin the story because the Rebels wouldn't have a chance to save the day but the empire doesn't want that. So why not jump with the super laser facing the planet? please help me make sense of this plan. Thank you.

Comment: There was a planet in the way, this is why they couldn't shoot. Rotating the Death Star to face the correct direction is trivial.

Comment: It does seem like they could have made used scouts and made multiple hyperspace jumps to reach the system without having to wait long enough for a rebel strike team to hit them.  Though I guess they just assumed the battle-station was invincible.